# PNChart keeps crashing when trying to load array points to plot

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, graphing

Hi I am using PNChart library (https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart) and when I am trying to put my array of values to be plot it keeps crashing. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is my code

```
[graph setXLabels: paymentAmounts];

// Line Chart No.1
    NSArray * data01Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:balanceWithoutChar];
PNLineChartData *data01 = [PNLineChartData new];

    data01.color = PNFreshGreen;
data01.itemCount = graph.xLabels.count;
data01.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
CGFloat yValue = [data01Array[index] floatValue];
return [PNLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
};
// Line Chart No.2
NSArray * data02Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:interestLabels];
PNLineChartData *data02 = [PNLineChartData new];
data02.color = PNTwitterColor;
data02.itemCount = graph.xLabels.count;
data02.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
CGFloat yValue = [data02Array[index] floatValue];
return [PNLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
};

graph.chartData = @[data01, data02];
[graph strokeChart];

}
```

This is the error i keep getting "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d43850"

This is the values of balanceWithoutChar array:

(
        "458524.43",
        "417014.30",
        "375469.58",
        "333890.23",
        "292276.24",
        "250627.57",
        "208944.19",
        "167226.07",
        "125473.19",
        "83685.52",
        "41863.02",
        "0.00"
     )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`graph.xLabels` is expecting an NSString.

Remember that in Objective-C, NSString is prefixed with an `@`.

You can use something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    [balanceWithoutChar insertObject:label atIndex:i];
}
```

where `dataArray` is an array of your raw (float?) data.

This way you'll end up with `balanceWithoutChar` looking like it should,

```
@[@"458524.43", @"417014.30", @"375469.58", @"333890.23", @"292276.24", @"250627.57", @"208944.19", @"167226.07", @"125473.19", @"83685.52", @"41863.02", @"0.00"]
```